# Why TCPReplay show warning when packets replayed on loopback interface?

Tags: networking, loopback

When I use following command to replay `1.pcap` over `lo`:

```
tcpreplay --mbps=10 --intf1=lo 1.pcap
```

Then I see these warning:

> .Warning: Unsupported physical layer type 0x0304 on lo.  Maybe it works, maybe it wont.  See tickets #123/318

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you see in the warning message, this message appear because L2 layer of loopback interface is different from other interfaces such as Ethernet. Because of limitation of `PF_PACKET` API in linux, `tcpreplay` cannot support loobpack just in L2 layer.

If you are using tool that are not sensitive to L2 header, ignore this warning, else you must replay packet on other interfaces.